# GridView - "enter" multiple rows into edit mode using checkboxes from codebehind (on button click)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I need some help again.

I have a `GridView` with `CheckBox`es in first column. If a user checks multiple `CheckBox`es and clicks a button I need to display selected rows in edit mode. How do I do that? Any tips?

Some sample code, how I imagine it.

Here is my Gridview MyGV:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbColumn1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="labColumn1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbColumn2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="labColumn2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column2") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="EDIT" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />
```

In code behind I bind that `GridView` to display data from SQL table (no problem there). Now I need it to enter selected rows into edit mode (ONLY selected rows) when I click the EDIT button.

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGV.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChkBox");
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            // ENTER EDIT MODE - Help needed here!! :)
        }
    }
    BindGridView();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GridView only one row can be in true edit mode at the same time. See question below for a possible workaround:

[Put multiple rows of a gridview into edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314845/put-multiple-rows-of-a-gridview-into-edit-mode)

Comment: I looked into the answer you suggested. Nice idea, I'll try to implement it. Thnx. :)